# Can't restore to backups after removing disk in Time Machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, hard-drive, external-disk

I've been using a WD 2TB HD for the last two months to handle my Time Machine backups for my Macbook Air. Yesterday, I wanted to set it up to handle backups through the network. In the Time Machine interface, I selected "Remove Disk" for this WD drive and confirmed "Stop Using This Disk" in the following confirmation. This confirmation states that "Your existing backups will not be deleted."

After playing around with the network setup, I found it wouldn't work to my needs and decided to just get the drive set back up with my laptop. After clicking "Select Backup Disk" and then "Use Disk" for the HD, it's as if that drive has never been used before. See screenshot below:

[image]

Furthermore, when entering into Time Machine, none of my backups appear in the UI. When browsing the drive through the Finder, the Time Machine files are still there, so I know that the data is not lost. I just can't access it.

What can I do to get everything back up and running again like it was before?

System info: Mavericks (10.9.1), MacBook Air 13" Mid 2011, Western Digital 2TB My Passport

---

Update 12/29/2013. Additional info: here is what I see when I click "Select Disk" again, after I've re-added the drive. As you can see, the drive appears twice, once as a Time Machine backup, and again as a regular drive.

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Update 12/30/2013. I am now able to access previous backups (by using [Kent's recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115268/3186) of using <kbd>option</kbd> plus clicking the Time Machine menu bar icon), but the interface is so slow that it could appear to be not working if one wasn't patient enough. Something blocking on the main thread, perhaps?

The main issue to solve now is how to get incremental backups working from the last full backup made to the drive, instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: I have a related question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114478/how-do-i-repair-a-corrupt-time-machine-sparsebundle-that-is-only-showing-the-mos

Comment: When you  selected add disk. Did you get two items named as the Western Digital 2TB My Passport drive you used.

Comment: @markhunte Good question. I'll have to check (away from the machine at the moment).

Comment: @markhunte I just checked whether I can see two disks--the answer is yes, I can! After re-adding it, it appears as a Time Machine disk, but then there is also a second, identical drive that seems to be "available". Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/QB95/5pi0aQ00

Comment: I asked because I vaguely remember I may have had the same issue a while back and changed my selection to the other identical name thus getting my backups back.but not 100% sure if I remember right. It maybe worth you trying it

Comment: Did what I suggest actually solve the main issue?

Comment: @markhunte Unfortunately, selecting the "other" disk in the interface did not solve the problem. It basically just reset the counter once again.

Comment: Ah just re read your update so it was working all along just slow to display in GUI

Comment: @markhunte Well, 50% of it I think has been working all along (the accessing the previous backups part). The part where it continues doing incremental backups hasn't been solved.

Comment: A possible related issue reported here, [How do I undo "Remove Disk" from Time Machine?](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24257065?tstart=0#24257065?tstart=0)

Answer (score 4):

To access the previous backups, press the <kbd>option</kbd> key when clicking on the time machine menu bar icon.  You'll see an item to browse other time machine disks.

Comment: This is an awesome idea, but when I click browse and select the disk, it displays backups, but only the ones made *after* I had reconnected it, and not the ones created beforehand. EDIT: Actually, it seems I can *view* those backups, but they appear in a light pink font and I cannot select them.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm shooting in the dark now; but, there's an older thread on Apple's forums that suggests to first open a new finder window, navigate to the "Computer" (press command+shift+C), and then open Time Machine.  I suspect this won't work in your case, but it's worth a shot.  https://discussions.apple.com/message/15776109#15776109 is where I got that info.

Comment: Just tried it...I am now able to retrieve those prior backups! Now onto the question of whether Time Machine can start back with incremental backups from the pre-existing data instead of doing a full one.

Comment: You might check http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/command-line-method-to-backup-using-two-time-machine-disks  There is some information on a command-line hack that convinces the computer to use a specific disk (BackupAlias) as well as a link to a slightly easier (since 10.7) way that may do the same thing.  I've not tried either method; but, it looks reasonable.